# ExtJS how to query records or call methods on a server using MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, extjs4

In an ExtJS application that uses MVC design, how can you query records from a php/mysql back end or call methods on the php back end while passing objects or array data?

All of the examples I have seen of models, proxy, MVC style, show simple examples such as

```
myModel.load(123, ...
```

All it does is load record with id 123.  Most of the examples also show how to create records or update existing records.

But what if I want to load a user with first name of "John"?

It looks like MAYBE I need to use a Store?

In other environments (such as AMF messaging) I usually pass objects - for example, creating a 'User' object or collection, setting the name, the calling something like

```
 userService.Load(userObject);
```

Then, on the server side I receive the request for "userService.load" (a method on the server), then receive the object, pull out what I need, and return a result object (or array collection).

Are there any examples on how to query using models/proxies in ExtJS?

Then, how to use objects?    I thought the model would be the object and pass itself via the proxy definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it, somehow, wrong with Model, Model is just a definition of a data Model, think of it as a row definition on the client side, lets use some example:

We have on our backend a table for the orders, we might represent it on the frontend with a Model, like this:

```
var orders = Ext.define('Orders'. {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields:['id', 'user_id', 'qty', 'item_ordered'],
            proxy: { 
                       type:' ajax', 
                       url: 'orders.php',
                       reader: {
                                   type: 'json',
                                   root: 'orders'
                               }
                   }
        });
```

That is a really simple Model, now, if i want to fetch just one order at the time, i can use the model to do it, like this:

```
var order = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Orders');
order.load(1); //This will load the order with id = 1
```

But, on the other hand if i want to get all the orders (ex, for a user), i'll do it with a `Store`, stores manage collection of models, we can say its a view of a table with a collection of rows composed of structured data that you can define in your `Model`, lets define a simple store that use our model:

```
var ordersStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model:'Orders',
            proxy: {
                       type: 'ajax',
                       url : 'orders.php',
                       reader: {
                                   type: 'json',
                                   root: 'orders'
                               }
                   }
    });
/* This should get us our orders for the user with id=1 and also answer your
question about how to get a user with name = 'John', you can do it in the same way */
ordersStore.load({params:{user_id:1}});
```

That's about fetching data, how do you handle in your server with PHP, well, i believe that is another question.
About the ´Model´ passing itself via ´Proxy´ that is true when adding or updating ej:

```
order.set('qty', 4);
order.save(); // This will pass the 'Order' Model to the server.
```

Or:

```
var newOrder = Ext.create('Order', {user_id:1, qty: 2, item_ordered: 66});
newOrder.save(); // This will pass the 'Order' Model to the server too.
```

Here you can get some more info about it too:
[Ext Store docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)
[Ext Model docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)

I hope this will get you started with Models and Stores.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.   For others, this was also very helpful - at least for the Direct data store which I am using - this shows how to set up the model/store/proxy CRUD framework with a grid: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/direct_grid_pt1  ALSO, for the MVC part, this is a start: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture, then read: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/mvc_pt1 (3 parts), last, I used some from this I like that the view panel is created within the controller, not the app: http://www.extjsframework.com/mvc/simple-mvc-application